# How to fix TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.ext.commands.context.Context'>?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I'm coding a Discord bot using discord.py 2.3.2 with the [Interactions API](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f#file-09-hybrid_commands-py). When running my snippet of code:

```
@commands.hybrid_command(name='help', with_app_command=True)
async def help(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.reply("Test was good!")
```

I get the error

```
line 65, in <module>
    async def help(self, ctx: commands.Context):
TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.ext.commands.context.Context'>
```

What is causing this and how should I go about fixing it?

I have done my best to follow the Interactions API documentation, to no avail. The error I'm getting is in a line copied directly from a doc example. My command

```
@bot.tree.command()
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
    await interaction.response.send_message("test successful")
```

works just fine, but not the hybrid command.

Comment: im not sure but since a hybrid command also application command you can't use the `.reply()` method. Try `.send()` instead.

Comment: @boez still nothing. The error is on the line that says `async def help(self, ctx: commands.Context):`

Comment: are u using a cog?

Comment: No I'm not. I'm still super new to python and don't know what those are

Comment: i see probably thats why this error occurs, although i wouldnt recommend for a beginner to start with bot projects since they are more advanced, i'll provide a answer with a solution

Comment: With lots of google help, I'll do it! It won't be anything big or flashy or mainstream, but it will be fun and it'll be mine!

Comment: then good luck on your journey 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood in the comments you are not using a [Cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20cog#discord.ext.commands.Cog), thatswhy you can't use the `self` keyword and so the first paramater would be [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context).
Also change your decorator to

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name="help", with_app_command=True)
```

So your final code would look like this:

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name="help", with_app_command=True)
async def help(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.reply("Test was good!")
```

Comment: That worked to fix my issue, but now the commands won't sync properly. Here's my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77276584/issue-syncing-hybrid-commands-discord-py). Thanks for answering this one!