# Issue syncing hybrid commands discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

As an extension to my [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77269425/how-to-fix-typeerror-unsupported-type-annotation-class-discord-ext-commands-c/77271080#77271080), I am now having problems syncing my hybrid command. My code is as follows:

```
import discord
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from typing import Literal, Optional
from discord.ext.commands import Greedy, Context


intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
intents.message_content = True
load_dotenv()

bot.help_command=None

..........

#Startup confirmation message
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord! Version {discord.__version__}')

@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.is_owner()
async def sync(
  ctx: Context, guilds: Greedy[discord.Object], spec: Optional[Literal["~", "*", "^"]] = None) -> None:
    if not guilds:
        if spec == "~":
            synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        elif spec == "*":
            ctx.bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=ctx.guild)
            synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        elif spec == "^":
            ctx.bot.tree.clear_commands(guild=ctx.guild)
            await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
            synced = []
        else:
            synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync()

        await ctx.reply(
            f"Synced {len(synced)} commands {'globally' if spec is None else 'to the current guild.'}"
        )
        return

    ret = 0
    for guild in guilds:
        try:
            await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
        else:
            ret += 1

    await ctx.reply(f"Synced the tree to {ret}/{len(guilds)}.")


@bot.hybrid_command(name='help', with_app_command=True)
async def help2(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("Test was good!")

@bot.tree.command()
async def test1(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
    await interaction.response.send_message("test successful")


.................
    

bot.run(os.getenv("token_dev"))
```

When I do the `$sync` command, it will update the `test2` `@bot.tree.command()` will sync and then run just fine with whatever changes I make to it, but my hybrid command will not. I also have an [extra command for some reason?](https://imgur.com/a/3QEuaqI) I think it's left over from when I was tinkering with a different API but I don't know how to remove it.

When I do `$sync`, it sends the message `Synced 1 commands globally`, and my command `test2` will sync and run just fine with any changed I make to it. My hybrid command, however, will not. I also appear to have an extra command that won't go away no matter how many times I sync, and I'm not sure how to remove it. If I try to run it I get:

```
2023-10-11 17:45:35 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command tree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\malak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1089, in wrapper
    await self._call(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\malak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1221, in _call
    command, options = self._get_app_command_options(data)
  File "C:\Users\malak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1125, in _get_app_command_options
    raise CommandNotFound(name, parents)
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'test' not found
```

and if I try to run my hybrid command with `$test1` it gives me my "command not found" error I have. `/test1` does nothing. When running in Debug mode no errors are given.

EDIT: I changed `@commands.hybrid_command(...)` to `@bot.hybrid_command(...)` and now when doing `$sync` it will say it has synced two commands, and will work fine if I do `$test1`, but still nothing for the slash.

I should also add then when doing `/test` it will auto-complete, but when I send it the application does not respond.

EDIT 2: Okay so I forgot that it can take a while for commands to sync up, and so now `test1` is present in my slash-commands list, but so is the normal `test` which I don't want to be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord! Version {discord.__version__}')
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This will sync every `bot.tree.command()` when you run the bot.

Comment: Didn't work. I already have a command that does this and that's not the issue. Everything else will sync fine except that one command.

Comment: Then just delete the `-> None` part.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was cached somewhere in the Python files so all I had to do was re-install Python and sync the commands again.

Comment: ...that feels like overkill?